# React useEffect hook causes DOMException: User activation is required to request permissions

Tags: reactjs, permissions, file-system-access-api

I have a React `useEffect` hook that will read local files previously approved by the user.

To read the files, it uses the `[FileSystemHandle.queryPermission()][1]` method, which if not `granted` will prompt the user for access using the `FileSystemHandle.requestPermission()` method.

The problem is that this happens before the user has a chance to interact with the page, which causes the `DOMException: User activation is required to request permissions.` error.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the requirement for user activation defined by Google and now incorporated into the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#tracking-user-activation).

The way to work around this is to remove this action from executing as part of the `useEffect` hook and instead prompt the user to perform the action first.

In my case the UI will show an indicator that the content needs to be updated, with a small button to trigger the action. This qualifies as user activation and the process runs without the error.

```
let file, perms

perms = await fileHandle.queryPermission()

if (perms === 'granted') file = await fileHandle.getFile()
else if (perms === 'prompt') {
  setButtonForRetry(true)
}
```